# Firebase Functions 'use strict'-mode / Ecmascript versions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using node 10 on firebase functions. Without 'use strict', this peace of code is valid:

```
({ id, title, createdAt, updatedAt } = post);
```

but with strict mode, functions throws the error that `ReferenceError: id is not defined`.

I am just getting into backend development with JS, so I want to know, what is the best practice here. Some post on the internet says that with "use strict" your code might run faster. But the destructuring assignments reduce boilerplate code and make maintenance easier.

Does it matter at all on a Node server, eg when we are talking about Browser environments? If yes, can I change to a different Ecmascript version in Firebase where both the strict mode and destructuring is possible?

Comment: If that throws a ReferenceError, it means that you forgot to declare `id` somewhere. You should feel lucky: pointing out such mistakes is what strict mode is about!

Comment: @Bergi No, I did not forget the attribute; it is mandatory, every object has it. I have no errors when not using strict mode

Comment: I was not talking about the `post.id` property. I was talking about the (supposedly local) variable `id` that you try to assign to.